# how to stub out namespaces for unit testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am new to cpp. How would I unit test bar in clazz without invoking anything in Foo?

clazz.h

```
class Clazz {
  public:
    void bar (); //its implementation will call Foo::foo ()
}
```

myfile.cc

```
namespace Foo {
  void foo () { /* do something */   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `Clazz::bar()` invokes something in `Foo`.

Comment: You'll have to add a proper constructor, so you can [accept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) the instance of `Foo`. This way you'll call the `Foo::foo` method in production and an alternative method (or class) in test code.

Comment: @juanchopanza: it is no longer a unit test if i call the actual implementation of Foo.

Comment: @Caramiriel: Foo is not a class. It is a namespace. How do i pass it in?

Comment: @user1811367 You can't "call Foo". But that is independent of unit testing `Clazz::bar()`. Just unit-test `Clazz::bar()`. If you can't, it isn't a unit.

Comment: @user1811367: Either you wrap it in `#if` directive, which is compile-time (and not really neat in my opinion) or pass pointers to functions to the constructor at runtime. Doesn't have to be a class. As long as it is something callable.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. The idea is to test the real software, not some 'test' version of it.

Comment: @EJP unit tests should only test the unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Caramiriel suggested, your class `Clazz` can accept a pointer to func `foo` that you can substitute for another dummy function for your unit test.

```
class Clazz
{
  public:
    typedef void (*fooFunc)();

    Clazz(fooFunc foo) : m_fooFunc(foo) {}
    void bar (); //its implementation will call Foo::foo ()

  private:
    fooFunc m_fooFunc;
};

namespace Foo 
{
  void foo () { /* do something */   }
}

void dummy() { }

Clazz a(Foo::foo);
Clazz b(dummy);
```

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer I work at Typemock.

There is a way to test this without creating wrappers, or changing methods to virtual, or adding indirection logic or passing a function pointer.

```
//Use Isolator++ to fake foo.
WHEN_CALLED( Foo::foo() ).Ignore();
```

This is using [Typemock Isolator++](http://www.typemock.com/isolatorpp-product-page). Here is the complete code:

```
namespace Foo 
{
  void foo () { throw "error";  } /* we want to fake this implementation */
}

class Clazz
{
  public:
    void bar () //its implementation will call Foo::foo ()
    {
        Foo::foo();
    }
};


TEST_F(FakeStaticMethods, DontFailWhenBarIsCalled)
{
    WHEN_CALLED( Foo::foo() ).Ignore();
    Clazz c;
    c.bar(); // WOW! code will not fail, no changes to production code
}
```

Comment: The mock is strong with this one ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have two solutions:

1. wrap the function using a class, and then inject that class into `Clazz`. This makes it easy to intercept the function call, and prevent it from happening.
2. don't link in the implementation of `Foo::foo` and instead provide a dummy implementation/mock.

Let's go through your possibilities.

### 1

You woul need to write a wrapper that provides the functionality of your global function. Let's do this using an interface, and implementing it:

```
class AbstractFooWrapper {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class FooWrapper : public AbstractFooWrapper {
public:
    void foo() override {
        Foo::foo();
    }
};

class FakeFooWrapper : public AbstractFooWrapper {
public:
    void foo() override { }
};
```

We also need to alter `Clazz` to make use of the wrapper:

```
#include <memory>

class Clazz {
public:
    Clazz(std::unique_ptr<AbstractFooWrapper> foo) : foo_(foo) { }
    void bar();  // will call foo_.foo()
private:
    std::unique_ptr<AbstractFooWrapper> foo_;
};
```

This way you can test `Clazz` by simply providing it a heap allocated `FakeFooWrapper` instead;

```
Clazz c(std::unique_ptr<AbstractFooWrapper>(new FakeFooWrapper));
c.bar();
```

That will make your code easier to test and more composable.

But if you would like to change as little as possible in your code have a look at the method 2.

### 2

Separate the implementation of `Foo::foo` into another file, let's call it `foo.cpp`. That way you have two files

**foo.h**:

```
namespace Foo {
    void foo();
}
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
void Foo::foo() { 
    // do something that you dont want to do during testing
}
```

Now we create a third one, with a fake implementation:

**fake_foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
void Foo::foo() {
    return;
}
```

You then write your tests normally for `Clazz`, but you link against `fake_foo.o`.

```
g++ test_clazz.cpp clazz.cpp fake_foo.cpp -o test_clazz
```

This way the the real `Foo::foo` doesn't get called.

Once you have separated definition from declaration, you wouldn't even have to write a separate implementation, you could use a mocking framework of your choice. In [turtle](http://turtle.sourceforge.net) (works well with boost test), this is easy to do.

```
#include <turtle/mock.hpp>
namespace Foo {
    MOCK_FUNCTION( foo, 0, void(void) );  // name, arity, signature
}

TEST_CASE( clazz_bar_test )  // call your testing frameworks macro
{
    Clazz c;
    MOCK_EXPECT( Foo::foo ).once();

    CHECK( c.bar() );  // whatever it is you want to test
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As long as `foo()` can be properly unit tested beforehand, I don't see an inherent problem in using it inside the the unit test for `Clazz`. Or would you also stub out an STL algorithm?
2. If it is a concern for you, that you cannot unit test `Clazz` without `foo()` then this is an indication for your code being not sufficiently modularized and you can e.g. use function pointers, templates or `std::function` to change that.
3. If you still want to test `Clazz` without `foo()` and without changing the structure/interface of `Clazz::bar()` you can do one of the following (more or less ugly and error prone) things:
   3.1 use `#if`s inside the class
   3.2 Change the using directive from `using Foo` to `using FooMock`
   3.3 Have a separate build configuration, in which you don't compile `Foo.cpp` but `FooMock.cpp` (you will need a separate configuration for testing `foo()` then)

Comment: There are lots of reasons why you wouldnt want to call the real impl. Off the top of my head. 1) you make a non backwards compatible change to foo And you dont want to change a million tests. 2) foo calls the network or db or something 3) using the real foo requires you to mock out too many objects just to setup your tests. Stl generally dont have these issues

Comment: @user1811367: Let me rephrase that: There is nothing INHERENTLY bad with calling a function outside of your module. If foo itself is not suited for unit testing, then of course, using it in another unit test is also not sensible. That is why I listed the other options. Regarding your first point: under which circumstances would you have incompatible versions in your workspace and still need to test the outdated parts of the code?

Comment: For my first point, there are times where the interface for a function wouldn t change but the logic inside It would. For example if you have a function bool goodColor (Color c) that originally returned true for blue but now you decide to change it to red, you shouldnt need to change the funcs that use goodColor because the tests for those functions should not be concerned with what constitutes a good color. The goal to mock foo is such tha foo is not tested when i test bar.

Comment: @user1811367: I see your point, but I have a somewhat different view at it: In an ideal world, the interface specification (against which I code my unit-tests) doesn't only include the function declaration, but also its semantics. So either the purpose of your function is to perform some algorithm for which `goodColor` is a parameter and then it should probably also be a function parameter (either explicitly or implicitly via `this` or a passed generator function/object). ...

Comment: ... Or the value of goodColor is an inherent part of your functionality in which case it is also part of your unit's interface specification and if it changes, you have to change your tests accordingly - how do you know otherwise, that your function works correctly for the new value of good color?

Comment: So I would argue that good design dictates that the the responsibility of the 2 funcs be decoupled which means that the implenetation of goodColor should not be part of the rest of your functions. This means that you dont need to know how one function is implemented to test the other. (ie: print() should only print out good colors but shouldnt care what good colors are and a non interface change to goodColor should only affect the unit tests for goodColor and not print)

Comment: @user1811367: If the actual output of `print()` (its interface behavior) is supposed to depend on the output of `goodColor()`, shouldn't you write your unit test in a way, that it also takes into account the current output of goodColor? But anyway, there are obviously a lot of cases where you actually have to mock something, that you don't pass as a parameter and for that you can use one of the techniques listed in point 3.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I think we may be talking about the same thing here. I think the test for print() should depend on the _output_ of goodColor so that should be mocked out so that you don't need to manipulate the input into goodColor to get the output you want for the test for print(). This way, the test is less fragile and doesn't require a bunch of changes to be made when the goodColor implementation changes.

Comment: PS: Good discussion. I'm always interested to hear other perspectives  :)